# UPDATE SQL Query to update a table based on two dates

Tags: database, ms-access

i would like to update my query table based on two dates, i tried the following code but it didn't work

```
UPDATE [Stock Report] INNER JOIN Report ON [Stock Report].ItemID = Report.ItemID SET [Stock Report].Amount = SUM(Report.Amount) WHERE [Date Product Was Made] BETWEEN @AA AND @BB
```

My two query tables are Report and Stock Report

Report Table

```
ItemID|    Item      |Date Product Was Made|Amount|ProductID|Product Name
  10      Flour        11/17/2015            100     54       Saltbread
  11    Bran Flakes    11/17/2015            100     54       Saltbread
  10      Flour        11/17/2015            100     54       Saltbread
  11    Bran Flakes    11/17/2015            100     54       Saltbread
```

What i would like to see in Stock Report Table

```
ItemID|  Item      |  Start Date  |  End Date  |Amount
 10      Flour        11/16/2015    11/25/2015   200
 11     Bran Flakes   11/16/2015    11/25/2015   200
```

The dates can be any two random dates but the table should generate a total based on the amount used in between the date ranges. Wht]at would be the SQL code to complete this process

Comment: What is the datatype of [date product was made] column? does it store time value with date too? what are parameter values passed to the query?

Comment: you are almost there add group by item id to sum the rows

Comment: it just stores date no time @Harsh

Comment: Are these tables in the database or are they result sets from queries?

Comment: Could you explain more on that @EuphoriaGrogi

Comment: results sets from queries @Adish

Answer (score 0):

You tagged with mysql, sql-server and ms-access.

But answers will differ for each case.

Here SQLServer solution:

```
WITH SumAmount AS (
SELECT 
        ItemId
        ,SUM(Report.amount) as sum_amount
    FROM
        Report
    GROUP BY
        ItemId
)
UPDATE SR
    SET
        amount = SA.sum_amount
    FROM 
        [Stock Report] SR
        JOIN SumAmount SA ON SR.ItemID = SA.ItemID
    WHERE   
        [Date Product Was Made] BETWEEN @AA AND @BB
```

Supposed MS Access query (I'm not proficient with MSACCESS, going by http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/snytax/update-query.html):

```
UPDATE  [Stock Report] 
        JOIN (
            SELECT 
                    ItemId
                    ,SUM(Report.amount) as sum_amount
                FROM
                    Report
                GROUP BY
                    ItemId
            ) SA ON [Stock Report].ItemID = SA.ItemID
    SET
        [Stock Report].amount = SA.sum_amount
    WHERE   
        [Date Product Was Made] BETWEEN @AA AND @BB
```

Comment: I'm using MS-Access sorry about the confusing tags

Comment: whaaaat? you didnt specify on the first hand :P

Comment: My humblest apologies, can you still help me with the Ms-Access version of this code ?

Answer (score 0):

As EuphoriaGrogi mentioned, you were pretty close.

```
SELECT ItemID, Item, @AA AS StartDate, @BB AS EndDate, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM (YourReportTableQueryWith@AAAnd@BBParametersHere) AS SubQuery
GROUP BY SubQuery.ItemID,SubQuery.Item
```

More on GROUP BY  here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: i got an error trying to run the code my Report Table Query is      SELECT Rec.ItemID, Rec.Item, Iso.[Date Product Was Made], Rec.Amount, Iso.ProductID, Iso.[Product Name]
FROM Recipes AS Rec INNER JOIN [Interim Storage Orders] AS Iso ON Rec.ProductID = Iso.ProductID;    @Adish

Comment: Post your complete query here

Comment: SELECT ItemID, Item, AA AS StartDate, BB AS EndDate, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM (SELECT Rec.ItemID, Rec.Item, Iso.[Date Product Was Made], Rec.Amount, Iso.ProductID, Iso.[Product Name]
FROM Recipes AS Rec INNER JOIN [Interim Storage Orders] AS Iso ON Rec.ProductID = Iso.ProductID) AS SubQuery
GROUP BY SubQuery.ItemID,SubQuery.Item                                                                                                                                                                               error saying Circular reference caused by alias 'Amount' in query definition's SELECT list

Comment: i took the @ out cause it was giving me any error to post however i have it in my Access Databse

Comment: Changed the alias to TotalAmount. This should resolve the issue

Comment: it seems there is one error with the code it doesn't actually show me the totalamounts based on the date ranges i put in, it just totals everything desipte the date range, how can i fix this ? @Adish

Comment: Post the complete query you are using

Comment: SELECT Stock.ItemID, Stock.Item, Sum(Report.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM Stock INNER JOIN Report ON Stock.ItemID = Report.ItemID
WHERE (((Report.[Date Product Was Made])>=#1/1/2015# And (Report.[Date Product Was Made])<=#11/20/2015#))
GROUP BY Stock.ItemID, Stock.Item;              This seems to fix the problem